# TypeScript polymorphic return type

Tags: typescript

Let's say we want to implement data types hierarchy, what type should be used?

```
interface Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): ???
}

interface Array<T> extends Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): ??? { return new Array<T>() }
}

interface LinkedList<T> extends Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): ??? { return new LinkedList<T>() }
}
```

Polymorhping `this` is not working

```
interface Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): this
}

interface Array<T> extends Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): this { return new Array<T> }
  // ^ error `Error: type Array<T> is not assignable to type this`
}
```

Comment: Would returning the type exactly, eg `Collection<T>` and `Collection<T>` work? PS: there is no default interface method implementation in TS

Comment: No, because after `array2 = array1.map(...)` you won't be able to access `Array` methods anymore, it would be casted to `Collection`

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Collection%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20map(f%3A%20(v%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T)%3A%20Collection%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ZArray%3CT%3E%20implements%20Collection%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20map(f%3A%20(v%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T)%3A%20ZArray%3CT%3E%20%7B%20return%20new%20ZArray%3CT%3E()%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20foo()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20z%20%3D%20new%20ZArray%3Cnumber%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20q%20%3D%20z.map(()%20%3D%3E%2042)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aq.foo()%3B

Comment: @zerkms you are right! It somehow works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The honest use of polymorphic `this` is when you are actually returning `this`. Consider the following classes

```
export interface Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): this
}

class Array<T> implements Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): this { return new Array<T>() as this; }
}

class MyArray<T> extends Array<T>{ }

new MyArray().map(o=> true) instanceof MyArray // false, but map returns MyArray
```

Nothing forces `MyArray` to override `map` and return a correct instance, so when calling `map` on `MyArray` we still get an instance of `Array` (somewhat surprisingly I might say).

That being said there is not good way to model this in the type system, that is a class that when derived must implement a specific method without the class being abstract.

You could use polymorphic `this` and use the `constructor` property to protect against the above scenario, but there is no way to constrain the derived constructor to have no parameters (as the call below would require). So this solution is not fully type safe, and does use some type assertion to get the job done but I think it is as safe as it gets:

```
 interface Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): this
}

class Array<T> implements Collection<T> {
  map(f: (v: T) => T): this { return new (this.constructor as any)(); }
}

class MyArray<T> extends Array<T>{ }

console.log(new MyArray().map(o=> true) instanceof MyArray) // ture
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is *f-bounded polymorphism* (“overloading `this`”).

```
interface Collection<T> {
  map(this: Collection<T>, f: (v: T) => T): this;
}
```

The type of `this` is always used as the first parameter. Notice we can add more overloads. For example, to transform a `Collection<number>` into a `Collection<string>`, we could do:

```
interface Collection<T> {
  map(this: Collection<T>, f: (v: T) => T): this;
  map<U>(this: Collection<T>, f: (v: T) => U): Collection<U>;
}
```

Usage:

```
declare const collection: Collection<number>;

collection.map(x => x.toString())
```

Comment: Not sure what the point of `this: Collection<T>` in this case, could you explain it please ?. From my reading `this` will still be the same polymorphic `this` and the issue when implementing and returning `new Array<T>` is still present.

Comment: I wanted to illustrate the point that `this` parameter comes first. There are more useful applications of that of course (like making a method available only when `this` is a `Collection` of some specific `T`).

Comment: I am aware of other applications, was not sure if it had any role here, 10x for the clarification. You are right it might make it a bit more clear what `this` is as a type, although arguably it would be more like `map<TThis extends Collection<T>>(this: TThis, f: (v: T) => T): TThis;`.